# RSA Cryptography Signature doesn't work on server

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, signature

```
   public string SignSHA256RSA(string data,string privateKey)
    {
        using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
            rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _);
            var dataToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            var signature = rsa.SignData(dataToSign, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
        }
    }
```

Using the above code, I attempted to generate an RSA signature using a certain private key. It runs smoothly locally, however when I publish it to a server, the following error is generated:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyLite.ImportKeyBlob(String blobType, ReadOnlySpan keyBlob, Boolean encrypted, ReadOnlySpan password)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.CngPkcs8.ImportPkcs8(ReadOnlySpan keyBlob)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.CngPkcs8.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan source, Int32& bytesRead)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan source, Int32& bytesRead)
```

I look for answers online, but I can't discover anything helpful.
and it works perfectly in production when I comment out `rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out _)`

Comment: Odd error message since there is no file specified in any of the arguments to any of those calls.

Comment: Environment dependent issues are hard to identify, especially if the environments are not described (OS version, .NET version etc.). Is `privateKey` a Base64 encoded ASN.1/DER encoded private RSA key in PKCS#8 format? Did you try it with another key?

Answer (score 1):

```js
public static string SignTool(string data, string privateKey)
        {
            using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
            {
                //byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
                rsa.ImportFromPem(Config.Config.private_key.ToCharArray());
                /*
                make sure that your private key is in the format of 
                -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                your private key goes here
                -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
                */
                var dataToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                var signature = rsa.SignData(dataToSign,                                          HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue (C#/.NetCore 6 and 7, Windows). On my local dev pc my code worked. In an azure function the code worked ... but it did not work in a webjob, where it produced the same error. Its a bit of a strange error as well, since my code does not make use of a file. Your code also does not specify use of a file.

I came across this informative, short read, article: https://dusted.codes/how-to-use-rsa-in-dotnet-rsacryptoserviceprovider-vs-rsacng-and-good-practise-patterns

Based on that I decided to use RSACryptoServiceProvider as a replacement for RSA.Create(), and it worked immediately flawless. Hope it helps anyone.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, can you share some code how you did it?